# Pass a variable to .x$ in a formula of a map function

Tags: r, tidyverse, rlang

The first example works, but I'd like to move more of the repetitive code inside a function along the lines of example 2. I haven't found the right rlang approach to deal with the `.x$x`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

# This produces the desired result:
slope <- function(y, x){
  coef(lm(y ~ x))[2]
}

tribble(
  ~group, ~y, ~x1, ~x2,
  "a", 1, 1, 4,
  "a", 2, 2, 5,
  "a", 3, 3, 6,
  "b", 1, 4, 8,
  "b", 2, 6, 12,
  "b", 3, 8, 16
) |> 
  nest(data = -group) |>
  mutate(
    slope1 = map_dbl(data, ~ slope(.x$y, .x$x1)),
    slope2 = map_dbl(data, ~ slope(.x$y, .x$x2))
  )
#> # A tibble: 2 × 4
#>   group data             slope1 slope2
#>   <chr> <list>            <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 a     <tibble [3 × 3]>    1     1   
#> 2 b     <tibble [3 × 3]>    0.5   0.25

# I would like to use rlang to further simplify with something like this,
# but I can't see how to combine the variable with .x$:
slope <- function(x) {
  map_dbl(data, ~ coef(lm(.x$y ~ .x$x))[2])
}

tribble(
  ~group, ~y, ~x1, ~x2,
  "a", 1, 1, 4,
  "a", 2, 2, 5,
  "a", 3, 3, 6,
  "b", 1, 4, 8,
  "b", 2, 6, 12,
  "b", 3, 8, 16
) |> 
  nest(data = -group) |>
  mutate(
    slope1 = slope(x1),
    slope2 = slope(x2)
  )
#> Error in `mutate()`:
#> ! Problem while computing `slope1 = slope(x1)`.
#> Caused by error in `purrr:::stop_bad_type()`:
#> ! `.x` must be a vector, not a function
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the code working in the second version, your `slope` function will need to take a data argument as well as the name of the column you wish to regress. The column name then needs to make it into the formula of the `lm` call, which can be done in a few ways, perhaps the easiest being with some string parsing and `as.formula`. I would also use the `data` argument of `lm` for simplicity.

```r
slope <- function(data, var) {
  
  f <- as.formula(paste('y', deparse(substitute(var)), sep = "~"))
  map_dbl(data, ~ coef(lm(f, data = .x))[2])
}
```

So that you have:

```
tribble(
  ~group, ~y, ~x1, ~x2,
  "a", 1, 1, 4,
  "a", 2, 2, 5,
  "a", 3, 3, 6,
  "b", 1, 4, 8,
  "b", 2, 6, 12,
  "b", 3, 8, 16
) |> 
  nest(data = -group) |>
  mutate(
    slope1 = slope(data, x1),
    slope2 = slope(data, x2)
  )

#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#>   group data             slope1 slope2
#>   <chr> <list>            <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 a     <tibble [3 x 3]>    1     1   
#> 2 b     <tibble [3 x 3]>    0.5   0.25
```

Personally, I think that a more robust and versatile way to do it is by passing a formula:

```r
slope <- function(data, f) map_dbl(data, ~ coef(lm(f, data = .x))[2])

tribble(
  ~group, ~y, ~x1, ~x2,
  "a", 1, 1, 4,
  "a", 2, 2, 5,
  "a", 3, 3, 6,
  "b", 1, 4, 8,
  "b", 2, 6, 12,
  "b", 3, 8, 16
) |> 
  nest(data = -group) |>
  mutate(
    slope1 = slope(data, y ~ x1),
    slope2 = slope(data, y ~ x2)
  )

#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#>   group data             slope1 slope2
#>   <chr> <list>            <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 a     <tibble [3 x 3]>    1     1   
#> 2 b     <tibble [3 x 3]>    0.5   0.25
```